# How can I install Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I am a new user of Ubuntu. A while ago attempted to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 but it didn't work. It installed Ubuntu but deleted all the Windows file and I did everything correctly.

Now, I am new to the Ubuntu world and I like the OS and I would like to keep it and learn more but since my desktop is not used only by me, I need to install Windows 7 to dual-boot
alongside Ubuntu.

Is there any guide on how to do that?

I have got only one USB stick to save something and I don't even know how to download the Windows ISO file.

Comment: Exactly were it fails?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The windows installer is not likely to detect the Ubuntu install, and will overwrite the entire drive by default unfortunately.  There are ways to create separate partitions with Gparted\windows tools to create an additional install partition, but that can be a bit tricky.

In my experience, the Ubuntu installer does a good job of detecting Windows installs, and will do all the difficult partition resizing for you -- I have 3 computers dual booting Ubuntu\Mint\WinXP\Win7\Win8(non-uefi)

Steps for a simple clean dual boot(Ubuntu 13.10):

1. Backup all important files
2. Install Windows, and allow it to format entire drive(make sure install is 100% complete)
3. Boot into an Ubuntu live session(CD or USB)
4. Use the installer from the desktop
5. The installer *should* offer an option to install alongside Windows 7
6. Select how much space each OS gets and wait for it to finish.
7. Your computer will now boot into GRUB and allow you to select Windows or Ubuntu each time you boot.

It's unfortunate that this did not work for you the first time, but I know it *should* work, barring any encryption\odd partitions.

To help you get Windows iso on a bootable USB: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

Linux Mint(based on Ubuntu) also has an ISO to USB tool built in, and it may be installable in Ubuntu as well:http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/usb-creator

--Bryan

Comment: thank you bryan , i dont need to backup files because all my important files were deleted on the first time , anyway i acted quickly so i lost everything. ill inform you about the results and  i run on UEFI BIOS . thank you again :)

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Is it because I mentioned Linux Mint in place of Ubuntu? ;P